# How does it show completely on erl terminal in erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

It cannot show completely on erl  terminal  if the result too big in erlang. Is there any way to solve it.

```
[{rabbit_prelaunch_sup,'_',#Fun<erl_eval.42.3316493>},
 {rabbit_prelaunch_sighandler,'_',#Fun<erl_eval.42.3316493>},
 {rabbit_semver_parser,'_',#Fun<erl_eval.42.3316493>},
 {rabbit_semver,'_',...},
 {rabbit_runtime_parameter,...},
 {...}|...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rp(Term)` as shown in [shell functions](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html). When using `rp/1` it will print the term regardless of how deep it is.

> Prints a term using the record definitions known to the shell. All of Term is printed; the depth is not limited as is the case when a return value is printed.